# Github Flavoured Markdown - code blocks with empty lines won't render

Tags: javascript, markdown

I am trying to highlight a block of code in GFM using [Sundown](https://github.com/vmg/sundown) which is supposedly used at GitHub:

````
```javascript
var f = function()
{

}
```
````

The result I get is as follows:

````
<p>```javascript
var f = function()
{</p>

<p>}
```</p>
````

and is caused by having an empty line in the source code. However the same code snippet renders fine on the Github itself. Are there any good parsers(preferably in JavaScript) that can cope with this?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub pages docs [reference](https://help.github.com/articles/using-jekyll-with-pages) following libraries:

```
gem 'jekyll',     '=1.0.2'
gem 'liquid',     '=2.5.0'
gem 'redcarpet',  '=2.2.2'
gem 'maruku',     '=0.6.1'
gem 'rdiscount',  '=1.6.8'
gem 'RedCloth',   '=4.2.9'
```

There is no Sundown in the list. 
I suppose the same libraries are used for Markdown elsewwhere.